# c# files used by another process during convert tiff to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, converters, tiff

i  have no. of tiff files/images, now i want to convert on single PDF...

i wrote code for this one and it's work fine. but issue is, i am storing images on temp folder. and want to delete  those files after PDF generate.and it's giving me error.
**"Files is used by another process"**

my code is:

```
 string RootDirPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootDirPath"].ToString();
            string PDFDirPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDFDirPath"].ToString();
            string TmpFolderpath = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("d").Replace('/', '_');


            // creation of the document with a certain size and certain margins
            iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            // creation of the different writers
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream((PDFDirPath + PDFName + ".pdf"), System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            // load the tiff image and count the total images

            DirectoryInfo RootDir = new DirectoryInfo(RootDirPath + TmpFolderpath);
            FileInfo[] files = RootDir.GetFiles();

            System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = null;

            document.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
            {
                bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(RootDirPath + TmpFolderpath + "/" + files[i].Name);

                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

                img.ScalePercent(72f / img.DpiX * 100);
                img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                cb.AddImage(img);


            }
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();

            bm.Dispose();
```

plz let me know, what's wrong i made....Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should be in the loop and not outside:

```
bm.Dispose();
```

Comment: To avoid those errors you may use the `using` statement so your instance will be automatically disposed after use.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had same problem before. The reason is that when you are loading the images for creating pdf, you are not freeing the resources after use. Use following code to load use images.

```
private static BitmapImage GetBitmapImage(string imageFilePath)
{
    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
    bmpImage.BeginInit();
    Uri uri = new Uri(imageFilePath);
    bmpImage.UriSource = uri;
    bmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bmpImage.EndInit();
    return bmpImage;
}
```

This will automatically free the resources (images) you using after use..:)